# Is there any way for plots from matplotlib to be minimized/hidden?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm running `matplotlib.pyplot` in PyCharm and plots are always overlayed on the screen and don't get hidden when I try to change to another window. They also don't get minimized, they just do the animation of getting minimized and then unminimized. I know that calling `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` does fix this, but the quality of the plots is significantly worse. I'm on the latest version of macOS Catalina. Has anyone else had this issue and managed to fix it?